# Handling ViewController in SwipeView with Three ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I am following this link [CustomPageControlForPageViewController](https://github.com/terrybu/CustomPageControlForPageViewController) to implement SwipeView  menu. In this project, there are `only two ViewControllers` which involves in the swipe transition. But my requirement is of `three ViewControllers` like. So I am not getting any idea that, how to implement the `UIPageViewController delegate methods` with three ViewControllers which ll handle the transition from one view to other. Here is the code from the given link for two ViewControllers.

**swipe.h**

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *pageControlCustomView;

@end
```

**swipe.m**

```
@interface RootViewController () {

NSArray *viewControllers;
UIView *selectionBar;
int SELECTOR_WIDTH;
int SELECTOR_Y;
UIButton *leftButton;
UIButton *rightButton;

moveSelectorBarLeftBlockType moveSelectorBarLeft;
moveSelectorBarRightBlockType moveSelectorBarRight;

UIViewController *firstVC;
UIViewController *secondVC;
}

@end

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
SELECTOR_WIDTH = self.view.frame.size.width/2;
SELECTOR_Y = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + Y_OFFSET_BELOW_NAVBAR + HEIGHT;

UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

// Create page view controller
self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
self.pageViewController.delegate = self;

firstVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstViewController"];
secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];

viewControllers = @[firstVC];
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

}

#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
if (self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0] == secondVC)
    return firstVC;
return nil;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
if (self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0] == firstVC)
    return secondVC;
return nil;
}


- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed {
if (completed) {
    if (previousViewControllers[0] == secondVC) {
        moveSelectorBarLeft();
    }
    else {
        moveSelectorBarRight();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: please mark my answer correct if it really helps :)

Comment: Working on other parts of the app, i'll surely accept it when done with testing :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use your own array to store the order of your viewControllers.

Here is how I work with this delegate

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [self.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    if (index == 0) { return nil;}
    index--;
    UIViewController *targetViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];

    return targetViewController;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSUInteger index = [self.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    index++;
    if (index >= self.viewControllers.count) { return nil;}

    UIViewController *targetViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];

    return targetViewController;
}
```

Comment: You mean I have to define an array of ViewControllers like viewControllers =@[firstVc, secondVc, thirdVc];

Comment: First I would say, self.pageViewController.viewControllers will change its order unexpectedly. As I know, you can always take self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0] as current controller being displayed. 

so you have to control the sequence yourself and return it during the delegate methods.

so you better declare  viewControllers =@[firstVc, secondVc, thirdVc];

Comment: "As I know, you can always take self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0] as current controller being displayed" what do u mean by this line.

Comment: um... pageViewControllers means to help displaying multiple controllers. "one" at a time. so you can swipe the pageviewcontroller to switch to another controller.

and you can always use self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0] to get the "one"